# css fixed position in IE

Tags: css, css-position

i tried to fix this one myself unsuccessfully. 
I am trying to place a flash element in a fixed position in the bottom .

```
#ticker{ position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 12%; z-index: 6000 !important;}
```

and it workes in FF and chrome but not IE. 
i tried changing the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

but it didn't work . 
I read something about placing a fake element but I didn't quite got it..

Comment: It might also be helpful to share what version of IE you are testing in, as that can make quite a big difference sometimes.

Comment: redlena - The versions are 8 and 9

Comment: TheZ - the flash element is displayed where I placed it in the html doc and doesn't get replaced.

Comment: @user1392330: Could you provide a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/pen/) of your problem?

Comment: but it doesn't work in jsfiddle anyway..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got your fiddle working, you don't need to change your DOCTYPE.

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/xpjyY/1/

You forgot the closing bracket for your "object" in the css.

```
object[width=150]{z-index: -5 !important;}//Forgot the closing bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this doctype instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Somehow someone in Microsoft [thinks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531140%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that it's a good idea forcing developers to use Strict doctypes if they wish to use `position:fixed`. It's cool or something.

UPDATE: [this article](http://techblog.tonycollings.com/?p=516) describes several other solutions, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell it does work in IE9(works on my desktop). See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBacn/). I don't have IE8 at reach so i don't know if it will run in it.. (my guess is that it won't.. because microsoft... o,o)

Anyway.. hope it helps.. =)

Answer (score 0):

Only replace your **CSS** code with this

```
object[width=150]{z-index: -5 !important;}
#ticker,  #main_Ticker{ position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 12%; z-index: 6000 !important;}
```

You need to close

`object[width=150]{z-index: -5 !important;` this line

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/xpjyY/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected Code:

```
object[width=150]{z-index: -5 !important;}
#ticker,  #main_Ticker{ position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 12%; z-index: 6000 !important;}
```

You needn't change ANYTHING in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html

This should give you some insight as to how fixed positioning works, it's a boring, but necessary read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression in IE to achieve the same as position:fixed in other browsers. (So you need two different CSS files with `<!--[If IE]><![endif]-->`)

Just set the position to absolute and add the expression:

```
#fixeddiv{  
    position: absolute;
    top: expression(0+((e=document.documentElement.scrollTop)?e:document.body.scrollTop)+'px');
    left: expression(0+((e=document.documentElement.scrollLeft)?e:document.body.scrollLeft)+'px');}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:**
[**jsFiddle with Active Ticker Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3YTX/)

**Solution:**
SWF option `allowscriptaccess` was required to allow proper operation of your SWF ticker file.  Horizontal centering of the flash ticker was done using pure CSS wrapped in a couple of div's in `position:fixed` so it's always pinned to the bottom.

**Compatibility:**
This jsFiddle is done in **HTML5**, not using DOCTYPE Scrict and works in IE8 without issue.
For IE7, use separate style sheet and change `bottom:0;` to `bottom:5px;` for proper operation.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Status:**
Screenshot provided since **jsFiddle.net** is experiencing [**intermittent outages**](https://twitter.com/#!/js_fiddle/) for the last 2 days.